# Sprint navigation doesn't show in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

While i am working on managing my sprints in Visual Studio Team Services, all my sprint options on the left pane has disappeared, therefore i can't see my previous and future sprint work items when i select work items under backlogs tab.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens when you set or select a specific sprint as your "set as team's backlog iteration" and the solution for this is to the following:

1) From the project homepage in VS Team Services.

2) Click on "Configure Schedule and iterations" link under other links section.

3) Select "Iterations" tab.

4) Set "set as team's backlog iteration" option to the top level.

5) You will notice check boxes have shown, where you can select which iterations to show or hide.

6) That's all! you will be able to view all selected sprints either previous/current or future ones!

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this too, but could not find the Other Links section.  I had to do the following, but there must be a better way so this isn't necessary.

1. Go to the Project's home page
2. Click on the Gear icon to enter the settings area for the project
3. This should default to the Overview Tab, with a list of teams on the right.
4. Click on the team
5. Click on the Work tab
6. Click on the Iterations sub tab
7. Click on the green plus sign to add the new iteration created previously

Comment: In step 7, the iteration does not show up in the dropdown menu in my case. It does however appear once you start typing the iteration name in the textbox.